# Get score on fileds that detect angry behaviour - Python Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I have reviews for products in a dataframe 'dfa' from customers in the format below. I want to add another column with score/flag on how 'angry' the review sounds.

| Service_id | Review |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | Pathetic service, waste of money |
| b2 | The service was average and the cleanliness could have been better |
| v2 | satisfied |

In the example above, positivity and anger will be treated differently. b2 has a negative comment but it should not be considered angry.

Example (output)

| Service_id | Review | Anger_flag | Anger_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | Pathetic service, waste of money | Y | 0.9 |
| b2 | The service was average and the cleanliness could have been better | N | 0.2 |
| v2 | satisfied | N | 0.0 |

Also like the profanity library, does python have a list of words to detect anger ?

Comment: How would you interpret: "Buying this item wasn't a waste of money at all. Others judge the service as being pathetic, but my experiences show something else". All the "angry" words are contained, but in fact it is a pretty positive review. Just searching for words won't work in my opinion. I'm pretty sure I can write a review that contains a lot of praise, but the sarcasm will turn it into the contrary. Just compare: "They are the best" with "They seem to think they are the best". A Bayes filter could work, if well trained.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords can unfortunately be misleading, as @Ronald pointed out in the comments.

Another option is to:

1. manually label a dataset of a couple hundred reviews with a binary label (e.g. 1 = angry, 0 = not angry)
2. encode the reviews using a sentence transformer (e.g. [from huggingface](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2))
3. use the embeddings to train an 'anger detection' model (e.g. [an SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html))
4. use the model to predict the 'anger' score of your remaining reviews with some degree of accuracy.

If you're short on time, maybe you can train the model on the 'angry' subset of sentences from an existing labeled dataset (e.g. [from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/praveengovi/emotions-dataset-for-nlp)), although using a different data source for training may decrease performance on your reviews.